# Excel Convert Make/Model/Year Range into Individual Year/Make/Model rows

Tags: excel, vba, powerpivot

I'm attempting to systematically expand a table of Make/Model/Year Range combinations into individual year rows.  I've tried looking for solutions but none seem to match my use-case and I don't know the first thing about VBA so need a little hand-holding here.

I'm using Excel Office 365, I've tried figuring something out with PowerPivot and merging queries but none will accomplish what I need.

Here is the data I am working from (Columns A:D)

```
Make    Model      From    To
ACURA   MDX       2001     2009
ACURA   RDX       2008     2009
ACURA   SLX       1996     1998
ACURA   TL        1999     2008
ACURA   TSX       2008     2009
```

The desired output would be:

```
Year    Make    Model
2001    ACURA   MDX
2002    ACURA   MDX
2003    ACURA   MDX
2004    ACURA   MDX
2005    ACURA   MDX
2006    ACURA   MDX
2007    ACURA   MDX
2008    ACURA   MDX
2009    ACURA   MDX
2008    ACURA   RDX
2009    ACURA   RDX
1996    ACURA   SLX
1997    ACURA   SLX
1998    ACURA   SLX
```

...And so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Microsoft Query and a source Excel file with two named ranges MAKES and YEARS (second one is a single-column of years spanning the desired range)

Query:

```
SELECT MAKES.Make, MAKES.Model, YEARS.Year
FROM `C:\Users\userName\Desktop\Test.xlsx`.MAKES MAKES, 
     `C:\Users\userName\Desktop\Test.xlsx`.YEARS YEARS
WHERE MAKES.`From` <= YEARS.Year AND MAKES.To >= YEARS.Year
```

Comment: Thank you!! I had no clue that Microsoft Query existed.  I read a little more into it here: http://www.exceluser.com/formulas/msquery-excel-relational-data.htm.  Thank you Tim for your help.  I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Power Query. Format your source data (A:D) as a table, then something like:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Added Year List" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Year", each List.Numbers([From],[To]-[From]+1)),
    #"Expanded Years To Rows" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Year List", "Year"),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Expanded Years To Rows",{"Year", "Make", "Model"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Other Columns",{{"Year", Int64.Type}, {"Make", type text}, {"Model", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```